# Is there a way to write a REGEX pattern over multiple lines?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I often end up with ultra-complex and long regexps. PCRE @ PHP.

For a long time, I've been searching and looking for a way to do something like:

```
    preg_match('#blablabla...
blablablablablabla...
blablablablablabla...
blablablablablabla...
blablablablablabla...
blablablablablabla...
blablablablablabla...
blablablablablabla...
blablablablablabla...
blablablablablabla...
blablablablablabla...
blablabla#uis');
```

Instead of:

```
preg_match('#blablabla...blablablablablabla...blablablablablabla...blablablablablabla...blablablablablabla...blablablablablabla...blablablablablabla...blablablablablabla...blablablablablabla...blablablablablabla...blablablablablabla...blablabla#uis');
```

If I make actual linebreaks, that will become part of the regular expression. Perhaps not as an actual linebreak, but as whitespace. Unless I'm completely mistaken.

Is there some character I can use in the end of each row to say: "this is supposed to all be one line"?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, you could place the pattern in a variable (where you'd write it like this) and strip the newlines when feeding it into the regex functions.

Comment: Usea NOWDOC/HEREDOC string literal and use `/x` modifier. But you need to remember to escape literal whitespace and `#` then.

Comment: I'd suggest editing the title to something more search friendly, like "how to write a regex pattern over multiple lines". I think this is a good question and it'd benefit from a more accurate title in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) that supports variable interpolation (or [NOWDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) that does not support  variable interpolation) with an [`x` flag (modifier)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). See what the docs say about the quantifier:

> *x (PCRE_EXTENDED)*
> If this modifier is set, whitespace data characters in the pattern are totally ignored except when escaped or inside a character class, and characters between an unescaped # outside a character class and the next newline character, inclusive, are also ignored. This is equivalent to Perl's /x modifier, and makes it possible to include commentary inside complicated patterns. Note, however, that this applies only to data characters. Whitespace characters may never appear within special character sequences in a pattern, for example within the sequence (?( which introduces a conditional subpattern.

```php
// HEREDOC
$pattern_with_interpolation = <<<EOD
/
blablabla...  # comment here
blablabla     # comment here
/uisx
EOD;

// NOWDOC
$pattern_without_interpolation = <<<'EOD'
/blablabla... # comment here
blablabla     # comment here
/uisx
EOD;
```

**Mind** that you need to escape all `#` and literal whitespace chars in the pattern since `/x` flag allows using comments at the end of a line after `#` and insert any literal whitespace with formatting meaning, they do not match the corresponding chars.

**Example**

```php
$pattern_without_interpolation = <<<'EOD'
/
\d+      # one or more digits
\        # a single space
\p{L}+   # one or more letters
\#       # a literal hash symbol
/ux
EOD;
if (preg_match($pattern_without_interpolation, '1 pound#', $m)) {
    echo $m[0];
}
// => 1 pound#
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/FbDX5).